# Load Resource content of other document into recent document and execute its snippets - Evolution CMS (former ModX Evo)

Tags: modx-evolution, evolution-cms

I like to use a snippet (that I place in document A) to load content of document B and display it.

If it would be only HTML, it would be easy to load like that using the snippet:

```
$docdata = $modx->getDocument($docid, 'content', 1);
return $docdata['content'];
```

However, the document resource loaded *contains* snippets itself. And those will not be executed like this.

How can I: 1. load the content and 2. force the execution of the snippets thereafter.

PS for Mods: I have introduced the new tag [evolution-cms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evolution-cms) for this post, since modx evo is [continued](https://modx.com/blog/evolution-cms-has-a-new-home) with this new name at [evo.im](https://evo.im). See also [Github](https://github.com/evolution-cms/evolution/issues/569).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$docdata = $modx->getDocument($docid, 'content', 1);
$out = str_replace(array('[!', '!]'), array('[[', ']]'), $docdata['content']);
$out = $modx->parseDocumentSource($out);
$out = $modx->rewriteUrls($out);

return $out;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. The snippets in the loaded doc resource (content) appear still as plain text [!mysnippet!].

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer